# Import CSV script- make python 2.7 compatible

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, csv

I created the following script to import files into my django models. It works fine, but only when using python 3.4.

How can I change this script to make it run on 2.7?

Thanks,

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_fromcsv.py", line 18, in <module>
    l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')))
TypeError: 'errors' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

My import file:

```
import sys, os
import django

sys.path.append('/srv/apps/stashdDB/code')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'stashdDB.settings'

django.setup()

import stashd.models as m




import csv

l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')))

Gender_CHOICES = {
    'Male': 1,
    'Female': 2,
    'Unisex': 3,
}

Stock_CHOICES = {
    'in stock': 1,
    'low stock': 2,
    'out of stock': 3,
    'discountinued': 4
}

for i in l[1:]:
        cat = m.Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name = i[4])[0]
        prod = m.Product(
            name = i[0],
            link = i[1],
            description = i[6],
            brand = i[7],
            gender = Gender_CHOICES[i[8]] if i[8] in Gender_CHOICES else 3,
            store = m.Store.objects.get_or_create(store_name = i[2])[0]
            )
        prod.save()
        var = m.Variation(
            product = prod,
            variation = "default"
            )
        var.save()
        img = m.Image(
            variation = var,
            image = i[5]
            )
        img.save()
        size = m.Size(
            variation = var
            )
        size.save()
        price = m.Price(
            variation = var,
            price = float(i[3])
            )
```

etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', 'rb')))
```

Comment: Thank you. That has worked. It is VERY slow tho. Any cause reason for that you can tell through my code?

Comment: @Yian no. It is a standard read from csv file in 2.7. From the  incomplete listing of your program it is difficult to see what slows its down.

Comment: The code worked for a whilte, then gave me this error: `return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 156: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: I think i need to encode latin-1. How can I do this?